# Correct form to pass value to IntEdit and StringEdit from a method dynamics ax

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I dont know what is the correct form to pass values from method to the fields, I already put yes on autodeclarate and check if the value I send from the method match with the type of field, I dont have any error only doesn't work. In fact it works with the IntEdit but for example when I send 500 shows me 1 I dont hunderstand why

This is my code

```
private void method1(){
   int var = 500;
   Field.value(var); }
```

And I would like to know how to pass that values from the method to StaticText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set value of `StaticText` control in form you should use `text()` method of `StaticText`

***For example***

My `StaticText` is called **ST1** (`Autodeclaration = Yes`).

```
ST1.text("Some value");
```

If you need a method to return a value for `StaticText` try this:

```
public str setStaticText()
{
    int var = 500;
    return int2str(var);
}
```

Then in `init` method of form for example

```
public void int()
{
    super();

    ST1.text(this.setStaticext());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfect, now I know how it works, as you can see I'm really new with dynamics, I'm still learning, thank you so much, have a good day :D

Comment: Perfect, you're welcome. if you want can set this answer like correct. In case another person has a similar error knows to what is due. Near the buttons to score the answer you have a mark button in gray use this to set the answer like correct. Regards!